# In a group, all users except 1 can sign a document

Tags: digital-signature

I have setup a "collect signatures" workflow in a document library.  I have setup 3 groups for that document library. When a Word document is added to the library, it starts a workflow and at each stage of the workflow, the document is routed to a different group.

In the last stage of the workflow, the document is routed to the "IT Support" group and only a single user is required to sign the document.

I have one user who gets a "Read Only" error when she attempts to complete the "sign" task for that document.  I have tried 6 other users in that group and none of the other users have a problem signing the document.  What could possibly keep a single user from opening the document for signing?

Comment: Permissions for that user is my best guess. May be library, site or web app level restriction.